# CSS sibling selector ~ for non-common parent divs

Tags: html, css

I saw this tutorial on [CSS Filter Functionality](https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3FilterFunctionality/index3.html) and decided to play around it for a while. You have radio buttons, and when you select one, say, Radio A, all the items that belong to radio A's assigned category will be displayed and anything that doesn't fit that category will be hidden.

The radio buttons and associated elements are found under this code:

```
<section class="ff-container">

            <input id="select-type-all" name="radio-set-1" type="radio" class="ff-selector-type-all" checked="checked" />
            <label for="select-type-all" class="ff-label-type-all">All</label>

            <input id="select-type-1" name="radio-set-1" type="radio" class="ff-selector-type-1" />
            <label for="select-type-1" class="ff-label-type-1">Web Design</label>

            <input id="select-type-2" name="radio-set-1" type="radio" class="ff-selector-type-2" />
            <label for="select-type-2" class="ff-label-type-2">Illustration</label>

            <input id="select-type-3" name="radio-set-1" type="radio" class="ff-selector-type-3" />
            <label for="select-type-3" class="ff-label-type-3">Icon Design</label>

            <div class="clr"></div>

            <ul class="ff-items">
                <li class="ff-item-type-2">
                    <a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/366400-Chameleon">
                        <span>Chameleon</span>
                        <img src="images/1.jpg" />
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="ff-item-type-1">
                    <a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/272575-Tutorials-wip-">
                        <span>Tutorials (wip)</span>
                        <img src="images/2.jpg" />
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="ff-item-type-2">
                    <a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/372566-Flower">
                        <span>Flower</span>
                        <img src="images/3.jpg" />
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="ff-item-type-1">
                    <a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/138484-Symplas-website">
                        <span>Symplas website</span>
                        <img src="images/4.jpg" />
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="ff-item-type-3">
                    <a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/134868-TRON-Mobile-ver-">
                        <span>TRON: Mobile version</span>
                        <img src="images/5.jpg" />
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="ff-item-type-2">
                    <a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/347197-Cake">
                        <span>Cake</span>
                        <img src="images/6.jpg" />
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="ff-item-type-1">
                    <a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/186199-Tailoring-accessories">
                        <span>Tailoring accessories</span>
                        <img src="images/7.jpg" />
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="ff-item-type-3">
                    <a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/133859-App-icon">
                        <span>App icon</span>
                        <img src="images/8.jpg" />
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="ff-item-type-1">
                    <a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/188524-Event-Planning">
                        <span>Event Planning</span>
                        <img src="images/9.jpg" />
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>
```

And the main CSS behind the functionality is

```
.ff-container input.ff-selector-type-all:checked ~ .ff-items li{
width: 188px;
-webkit-transform: scale(1,1);
-moz-transform: scale(1,1);
-o-transform: scale(1,1);
-ms-transform: scale(1,1);
transform: scale(1,1);
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s linear;
-o-transition: -o-transform 0.3s linear;
-ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.3s linear;
transition: transform 0.3s linear;
}

.ff-container input.ff-selector-type-1:checked ~ .ff-items .ff-item-type-1,
.ff-container input.ff-selector-type-2:checked ~ .ff-items .ff-item-type-2,
.ff-container input.ff-selector-type-3:checked ~ .ff-items .ff-item-type-3
{
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s linear, width 0s linear 0.3s;
-moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s linear, width 0s linear 0.3s;
-o-transition: -o-transform 0.3s linear, width 0s linear 0.3s;
-ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.3s linear, width 0s linear 0.3s;
transition: transform 0.3s linear, width 0s linear 0.3s;
-webkit-animation: scaleUp 0.3s linear 0.4s forwards;
-moz-animation: scaleUp 0.3s linear 0.4s forwards;
-o-animation: scaleUp 0.3s linear 0.4s forwards;
-ms-animation: scaleUp 0.3s linear 0.4s forwards;
animation: scaleUp 0.3s linear 0.4s forwards;
}

.ff-container input.ff-selector-type-1:checked ~ .ff-items li:not(.ff-item-type-1),
.ff-container input.ff-selector-type-2:checked ~ .ff-items li:not(.ff-item-type-2),
.ff-container input.ff-selector-type-3:checked ~ .ff-items li:not(.ff-item-type-3)
{
-webkit-animation: scaleDown 0.3s linear forwards;
-moz-animation: scaleDown 0.3s linear forwards;
-o-animation: scaleDown 0.3s linear forwards;
-ms-animation: scaleDown 0.3s linear forwards;
animation: scaleDown 0.3s linear forwards;
}
```

Now lets say I try to put all the input type="radio" tags in their own div like:

```
<section class="ff-container">
            <div class="new-div">
                <input id="select-type-all" name="radio-set-1" type="radio" class="ff-selector-type-all" checked="checked" />
                <label for="select-type-all" class="ff-label-type-all">All</label>

                <input id="select-type-1" name="radio-set-1" type="radio" class="ff-selector-type-1" />
                <label for="select-type-1" class="ff-label-type-1">Web Design</label>

                <input id="select-type-2" name="radio-set-1" type="radio" class="ff-selector-type-2" />
                <label for="select-type-2" class="ff-label-type-2">Illustration</label>

                <input id="select-type-3" name="radio-set-1" type="radio" class="ff-selector-type-3" />
                <label for="select-type-3" class="ff-label-type-3">Icon Design</label>
            </div>

            <div class="clr"></div>

            <ul class="ff-items">
                <li class="ff-item-type-2"> (truncated....)
```

how can I modify the CSS selector:  `.ff-container input.ff-selector-type-all:checked ~ .ff-items li` so that it can reference the parent div's parent (because the "ff-selector-type-xx" and "ff-items" will no longer have the same parent) ?

The entire code & original tutorial can be found [here](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/01/09/filter-functionality-with-css3/)